# systemd-timesyncd.service won't start

Tags: 18.04, time, ntp, systemd-timesyncd

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-08-17 04:32:34 PDT; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
  Process: 4629 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd (code=exited, status=238/STATE_DIRECTORY)
 Main PID: 4629 (code=exited, status=238/STATE_DIRECTORY)
```

It still says this after I created /var/lib/systemd/timesync/.

Comment: Is there any more errors than just the status when you (re-)start it?

Comment: It worked previously: Jun 17 11:57:41 zathras systemd-timesyncd[696]: Synchronized to time server [2001:67c:1560:8003::c7]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).

Comment: It failed later that same day after an upgrade and reboot.
Jun 17 16:36:43 zathras systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synch.
Jun 17 16:36:43 zathras systemd[941]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed to set up special execution directory in /var/lib: File exists
Jun 17 16:36:43 zathras systemd[941]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed at step STATE_DIRECTORY spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd: File exists
Jun 17 16:36:43 zathras systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: process exited, code=exited, status=238/STATE_DIRECTORY
Jun 17 16:36:43 zathras Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: `ls -ld /var/lib/private'
`drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 17 14:57 /var/lib/private/`

Comment: The fix from Fedora (`chmod 0700 /var/lib/private`) does not fix the problem.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7659#issuecomment-352724406) to the chmod fix.  Works for RedHat, not Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It's working now.

```
    # chmod 700 /var/lib/private
    # rm -r /var/lib/private/systemd
    # systemctl start systemd-timesyncd
    # timedatectl status
                      Local time: Wed 2019-08-28 17:55:15 PDT
                  Universal time: Thu 2019-08-29 00:55:15 UTC
                        RTC time: Thu 2019-08-29 00:55:15
                       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
    # ls -ld /var/lib/private/systemd/timesync
    drwxr-xr-x 2 systemd-timesync systemd-timesync 4096 Aug 28 17:51 timesync/
```